# Issue around connecting to a MySQL database table

Tags: python

I have some code which tries to connect to a mySQL database and retrieve a query.

The connection code is in a module called `connection` and looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pandas as pd
import pymysql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

COMPANY_SERVER = create_engine(
    'mysql+pymysql://view_user:connectiondetails')

def read_sql(query):
    return pd.read_sql_query(query, COMPANY_SERVER)
```

I have omitted the connection details for security. But this connection has worked in the past.

I am trying to connect and query a database table (which is pulled in with variable name `table`) and trying returning a `DESCRIBE` of the table in the following way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from copy import copy
import pymysql
from sql.connection import read_sql  


class DBSnapData(object):
    def __init__(self,
                 start_dt,
                 end_dt,
                 start_point,
                 end_point,
                 variables,
                 table,
                 stock_id  
                 ):
        self.start_dt = start_dt
        self.end_dt = end_dt
        self.start_point = start_point
        self.end_point = end_point
        self.variables = variables
        self.table = table
        self.stock_id = stock_id  
        self.schema = self.load_schema()

    def load_schema(self):
        return run_schema_sql_query(self.table)

    def run_schema_sql_query(table):
        return read_sql('DESCRIBE %s' % table)
```

I am getting the following error output:

```
2018-01-17 22:34:02,717 (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1142, "SELECT command denied to user 'view_user'@'192.168.9.132' for table 'TBL_MKTDATA_SNAPS_AUS'") [SQL: 'DESCRIBE TBL_MKTDATA_SNAPS_AUS']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1182, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 470, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 166, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 322, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 856, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1057, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1340, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1014, in _read_packet
    packet.check_error()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 393, in check_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 107, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1142, "SELECT command denied to user 'view_user'@'192.168.9.132' for table 'TBL_MKTDATA_SNAPS_AUS'")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/scoleman/bin/export_mkt_data", line 405, in main
    extract_by_id(sc_id, bbg_ticker, bb_id, lot_size_changes)
  File "/home/scoleman/bin/export_mkt_data", line 346, in extract_by_id
    stock_id)
  File "/home/scoleman/git/sql_data/sx_data_adhoc.py", line 100, in __init__
    self.schema = self.load_schema()
  File "/home/scoleman/git/sql_data/sx_data_adhoc.py", line 106, in load_schema
    return run_schema_sql_query(self.table)
  File "/home/scoleman/git/sql_data/sx_data_adhoc.py", line 19, in run_schema_sql_query
    return read_sql('DESCRIBE %s' % table)  
  File "/home/scoleman/git/sql_data/sql/connection.py", line 17, in read_sql
    return pd.read_sql_query(query, COMPANY_SERVER)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 331, in read_sql_query
    parse_dates=parse_dates, chunksize=chunksize)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1084, in read_query
    result = self.execute(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 975, in execute
    return self.connectable.execute(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2064, in execute
    return connection.execute(statement, *multiparams, **params)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 939, in execute
    return self._execute_text(object, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1097, in _execute_text
    statement, parameters
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1189, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1402, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    exc_info
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 203, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 186, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1182, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 470, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 166, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 322, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 856, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1057, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1340, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1014, in _read_packet
    packet.check_error()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 393, in check_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/sit
```

If anyone could give me a pointer as to a solution it would be much appreciated.  I think the problem might be with `pymysql` in the connection but really am unsure.

Thanks

Comment: This looks like an authorization problem. You don't have permission to access that table. You should check your user permissions

Answer (score 0):

Your error says `view_user` doesn't have permission to query data on `192.168.9.132` this server.

You will have to do 
`GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO 'view_user'@'host_or_wildcard' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`  to allow your `user` to query on specified server.

Or

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'view_user'@'192.168.9.132';` to grant all priviliges.

P.S. To do above you will have to be `root` user. Use `mysql -u root -p` command to connect to mysql server.

Comment: Many thanks Kishor, to test the GRANT ALL code do I add this to the connection script? Thx

Comment: That is one time activity, you do it manually either by login using command line utility (mysql) or some mysql gui client.